# Complementary Sets in $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $U,V\subset \mathbb{C}P^2$ be complementary sets (ie $U\simeq V^c$) with $M=U\cap V$ a $3$-manifold. Assume further $M$ is orientable.

My question is, must it be the case that one of $i_*:H_2(U;\mathbb{Q})\to H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{Q})$ or $i_*:H_2(V;\mathbb{Q})\to H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2;\mathbb{Q})$ are non-zero.

I would be happy with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in place of $\mathbb{Q}$ as well.

Comment: If they are complementary sets, they do not intersect. :-)

Comment: Why not, $U$ is just homotopic to the complement set. They may still interest. 

Comment: @Prasit: That is correct. Also, if it was not clear, I additionally mean that $U\cup V=\mathbb{C}P^2$

Comment: Ok, so may I ask what do you mean by "complementary sets"? Does that mean that U and V are submanifolds with common boundary M?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. Basically take a orientable sub 3-manifold. Then it separates $\mathbb{C}P^2$. Take $U,V$ to be the two components along with their common boundary $M$.

Comment: If you mean '$ U \cup V = \mathbb{CP^{2}}$', then apply Mayer-Veitoris. Since $M$ is oriented $H_{2}(M)$ does not have any $2$ torsion. And the answer pops out. 

But I am sorry to say this not a mathoverflow problem. 

Comment: Thank you. I apologize, I'm still learning how to judge the difficulty of a problem.I should probably just try stack exchange first in the future :)

Comment: @Prasit: I don't see how Mayer-Vietoris alone solves the problem - could you elaborate on your argument?

Comment: I think, I was too fast to jump to conclusion, I am sorry about my previous comment. Though the statement is true if $M$ is simply connected. One thing which concludes that the above statement is true is $H_{2}(M) = 0$ with the required coefficient. Simply connected is one option. 

@Mathews: Can you elaborate on the kind of sets $U$ and $V$ are? Are they open? or a related problem that you are looking at if thats the case)

Comment: I am taking $U,V$ to be $4$ dimensional sub-manifolds whose intersection is their common boundary $M$ and their union is all of $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

It would be very nice if the result I stated were true in general without further assumptions.I would prefer $M$ to not have to be simply connected as that would mean we can only deal with $M=S^3$. In which case, I'm not sure how helpful your other requirement is either because $H_2(M)$ must be torsion free (follows by using Poincare' duality and UCT) and I think this means that $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z}_p)=0$ would imply $H_2(M;\mathbb{Z})=0$ again by UCT

Comment: And the last thing in my comment above means that $H_1(M)=0$ making the original statement trivially true. I want to avoid this, if possible.

I appreciate the comments, and I'm sorry for my long comment. Probably should have just done an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an argument using cup products, which shows that whenever $\mathbb{C}P^2=U\cup V$ for open sets $U$ and $V$, one of the inclusions $U,V\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^2$ must be non-trivial on second homology.

Working with coefficients in an arbitrary field $k$, cohomology is dual to homology. By the naturality of the Universal Coefficient Theorem, for an arbitrary subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}P^2$ we have a commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2;k)  & \cong & \operatorname{Hom}_k(H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2;k),k) \newline
 \downarrow & & \downarrow \newline
H^2(U;k) & \cong & \operatorname{Hom}_k(H_2(U;k),k)
\end{array}
$$
which shows that if $H_2(U;k)\to H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2;k)$ is zero, then so must be $H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2;k)\to H^2(U;k)$.

Omitting coefficients from now on, it follows that the generator $x\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ is the image of a class $x_U\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2,U)$. Likewise, $x$ is the image of a class $x_V\in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^2,V)$ if $H_2(V)\to H_2(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ is zero. But then by naturality of cup products, $x\cup x$ must be the image of $x_U\cup x_V\in H^4(\mathbb{C}P^2,U\cup V)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: This is a very nice argument, thank you.